# Update Panel working very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm writing an app in which user can register. While registering the one may choose several options and according to these regiester fields are visible or not and are required or not. 
I came up with an idea that all fields will be in in the updatePanel and when users changes registration options I would set visibility of these fields on the server side.

It works but incredibly slow and whats more on the FF I have the given error:

> The state information is invalid for
>   this page and might be corrupted

3 checkboxes with other fields are in the updatePanel

Each field is in dl tag with `runat="server>`

I had to do it like that cause for "required" option I simply add css class to this dl (need in in javascript validation. If field should be visible I set visible="false" for given dl and then that field for example FirstName with title and so on isn visible after postback.

Am I doing something wrong ? Why does it take so long (~4 min on localhost) and in firefox it doesnt really work (when I use debug I think that process completes without errors on ff, I dont understand that at all :)

If update Panel is so weak what would be other option to change visibility and adding required class to all dls. Logic is quite complicated and has to make query to DB so simple javascript would be quite tricky.

Thanks for any hints,

Oh and I'm using ASP.Net and cant upgrade on this project.

Thanks for help,
bye

Comment: Post your code - both the relevant part of the `.aspx` and the code behind, maybe you're doing something wrong there..

Comment: Do you use email send on the registration procedure ? if yes, then the communication with the server takes some time to complete.

Comment: I would dump UpdatePanels all together.  They carry a lot of overhead - posting back the entire ViewState and causing the full page lifecycle to commence (sometimes for just a small portion of the page).

Comment: @Kon - It sounds like the OP wants the full page lifecycle to be executed so that a complicated recalculation can occur. I've found this to -sometimes- be a legitimate use of an update panel. It works fine if Viewstate is off/minimized, page execution is fast, and the request/responses kept to a reasonable size.

Comment: @Tim, I gotcha.  Though I would argue that any complex calculations should not take place at the expense of the presentation/user-experience (i.e. separation of concerns).  :)

Comment: @Kon - completely agree. Regardless of the technology, the solution has to perform well.

Comment: Even though it's conditional, but I notice it will still rerun the Page_Load and Page_Init function, if it's heavy over there, it will affect the overall return speed. And if the form is dynamically generated, we need to reload the entire dynamic contents at the Page_Load, else the ViewState will failed on full postback. I haven't got any solution for this yet.

Answer (score 4):

Without code to look at, here are general things which will make an UpdatePanel slow:

- Large amount of form data (such as Viewstate) being posted. Uploaded data is often slower than downloading data (depending on connection type, such as a home connection where uploads can be 5x slower than downloads). Even though you can't see it, every form field on the page is posted back to the server (even if its not in the UpdatePanel).

I would suggest going through your request/response data in Firebug and making sure that your async requests are less than 5K and your responses are no more than 20K.

- A slow process on the server which is running when the UpdatePanel is posted. How does your code perform when the UpdatePanel is removed?
- JavaScript errors (yours and Microsoft's). Here is a link to a known bug and a fix that I have used myself: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2000262
- Massive DOM manipulation (doesn't sound like this is the case for you).

BTW, searching for the error message you reported gives many possible causes:
http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=The+state+information+is+invalid+for+this+page+and+might+be+corrupted

As always, minimize or remove dependencies on ViewState...it's the source of many problems and enables poor design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set update Panel properties update mode to `Conditional` instead of `Always`. Limit the number of controls you put into one update panel

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check, Page events etc. Research on page directive and property AutoEventWireup
Since performance is the issue you highlighted, you might want to check that as well. Update panel mode should be conditional. 
Check the triggers as well

Answer (score 0):

Try with these properties  values in`Page directive`. This is always at the top of   your page. Let other properties be there as they were before.  **Update panels should not be slow like you are reporting.**

```
 <%@ Page ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" EnableViewStateMac="false"
       EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

I would also like to add that if your database query that  you mentioned is complex, is taking a very long time, then the problem lies not with aspx page or update panel, but with your database query.  You will then need to profile your query and check how much time it's taking to execute. The way to go in that case would be to fine tune your query at database level.