# IE11 Slow to load ASP.Net Page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am working with an ASP.Net WebForms project that is using an UpdatePanel and in IE it is extremely slow to load the page, however in Chrome and FireFox this is not an issue at all.

I have seen and tried the answer here [ASP.NET website very slow Internet Explorer 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866439/asp-net-website-very-slow-internet-explorer-10)

I have also tried the suggested answer here too https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T268620

I also have the update condition set to conditional too as suggested here [Update Panel working very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367460/update-panel-working-very-slow)

I should also note that I have a repeater on the page too.

When looking at what is sent and recevied using Fiddler I am getting this result

```
Bytes Sent:      1,888      (headers:1,331; body:557)
Bytes Received:  5,280      (headers:148; body:5,132)
```

When navigating to the page, the data is loaded and appears immediately, but the page is not responsive which is the actual issue.

I would apprecaite all help in order to resolve this issue and speed up the performance in IE to mach (as close as possible) that of Chrome and FF.

- Edit -

Although this question has been asked, its been asked for different versions of VS.

I have resolved this now and have displayed the answer below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UpdatePanel Slowness in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267124/updatepanel-slowness-in-ie)

Comment: @Seano666 it is a duplicate question of a few questions, none of the answers were successful for me, however I have just found an answer that has reduced my load time by 13 seconds and will be posting an answer to this shortly

Comment: UpdatePanel is not really a good choice for speed in the first place. Have you considered using JavaScript and AJAX communicating back to a Web API?

Comment: @mason its whats been decided by the company I have joined today. Its something I will probably recommend to them but coming in on the first day and changing everything might not be the wisest idea

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and did consider deleting the question, however the problem has now almost gone give or take its still a 2 second load, rather than a 15.62 on average.

In Visual Studio the system has a function that needs turning off and whoever stumbles across this question with the same issue this will hopefully fix it for you too.

http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/

Its a combination of the DevExpress link and the turning off the option in Visual Studio.